# how to get rid of configuration/properties from the jar/war build files

Tags: java

How to get rid of configuration/properties from the jar/war build files such that there is no dependency on changes made the configuration/property files?

Comment: Put them somewhere outside of the web app?

Comment: Most application servers support of shared classpath area where you can place items which will be added to all application classpaths. Configure an appropriate location and place your configuration files there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using maven for build you can filter the resources through pom.xml as given below.

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.conf</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```